# CSS style only if one class isn't combined with another

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to style a `td` a certain way only if a class isn't combined with another class.

I'm doing something like this:

```
tr.transferred td[class^="sorting_"],
tr.transferred td[class*=" sorting_"] {
    background-color: rgba(153, 204, 255, 0) !important;
}
```

As much as I hate using `!important` I need them there so please bear with my code a little bit.

I need my selector to be updated such that it only applies the style if and only if the `td` has a class of `sorting_*` that is not combined with a class of `g-*`.

If you need any more info, let me know.

**EDIT:** *(additional info)*

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vrnw5az/5/) so you can try and see what my problem is.

#### HTML

```
<table class="display cell-border nowrap" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Police Officer</td>
      <td class="g-green">Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="transferred">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jane Smith</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td class="g-green">Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Nicole Curtis</td>
      <td>Manager</td>
      <td class="g-red">Retired</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false
  });
});
```

#### CSS

```
tr.transferred {
    background-color: rgba(153, 204, 255, 0.30) !important;
}

tr.transferred td[class^="sorting_"],
tr.transferred td[class*=" sorting_"] {
    background-color: rgba(153, 204, 255, 0) !important;
}

.g-yellow { background-color: rgba(226, 222, 112, 0.6) !important; }
.g-green { background-color: rgba(112, 226, 112, 0.6) !important; }
.g-pink { background-color: rgba(226, 112, 196, 0.6) !important; }
.g-red { background-color: rgba(226, 112, 112, 0.6) !important; }
.g-blue { background-color: rgba(112, 163, 226, 0.6) !important; }
```

#### What My Problem Is

So if you look at my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vrnw5az/5/) and play around with sorting, the colors work great except if you sort by the `Status` column. It should retain it's color green sorted or not.

Comment: @Pete I don't have control over the `sorting_*` classes as that is added by a Jquery library I'm using. For the `g-*` classes I made them for different colors `g-yellow`, `g-pink`, `g.green`, etc.

Comment: As with Paulie_D's solution I got this to work by using the `:not` selector which can be seen in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vrnw5az/7/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:not()` selector like so.

```
    [class*="sorting_"]:not([class*="g-"]) {
      /* your styles here */
    }
```

```css
.sorting_ {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}
[class*="sorting_"]:not([class*="g-"]) {
  background: red;
}
.g-green {
  background: green;
}
.g-pink {
  background: pink;
}
.g-blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sorting_ g-green"></div>
<div class="sorting_ g-pink"></div>
<div class="sorting_ g-blue"></div>
<div class="sorting_ grey"></div>
```

Works in Chrome/FF/IE11